# What permissions are required to execute a BigQuery stored procedure?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to grant someone the permission to execute a bigquery stored procedure but I don't want to grant them **roles/bigquery.admin**, I would rather grant only the required permissions via a custom role.

This led me to question the who a stored procedure executes as. I have a background in SQL Server and there is an option there to have a stored procedure execute as owner which means that it runs as the owner of the stored procedure and thus the permissions assigned to that owner...but I don't think there's anything similar in BigQuery.

In short, how do I grant someone permission to execute a stored procedure and do I need to grant the person executing the stored procedure the appropriate permissions on the datasets affected by the stored procedure?

I've pored over the documentation, mainly https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#bigquery-roles, but I can't find anything that provides clarity on this issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to User-Defined Functions? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

I think Stored Procedures is a similar concept, but not one that I'm familiar with in BigQuery

Comment: Hi. UDFs & stored procedures are similar. They're both considered to be "routines" in bigquery parlance but in the context of my question they are not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe "it runs as the owner of the stored procedure and thus the permissions assigned to that owner" is similar to the concept of "[Authorized Routines](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-routines)". As of September 2023, [authorized routines support stored procedures](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#September_25_2023).

Regarding the permissions needed, the `bigquery.routines.get` permission is required to execute a stored procedure or UDF. This is provided by `roles/bigquery.metadataViewer` and/or `roles/bigquery.dataViewer`. In addition, if it is not an authorized routine, then yes the query user also requires the appropriate permissions on the datasets affected by the stored procedure.

**Resources**:

- [BigQuery permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions)
- [BigQuery roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions_and_predefined_roles)

Comment: I don't see the option to +1 your submitted issue but I did star it

Comment: Ah, you're right. The +1 button is only visible to Googlers. Starring should do the same for normal accounts.

Comment: Authorized Routines were released in September 2023: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-routines